# aws s3 delete object not working

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to upload/delete image to/from aws s3 bucket using spring boot.

```
public class AmazonClient {
    private AmazonS3 s3client;

private void initializeAmazon() {
    AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(this.accessKey, this.secretKey);
    this.s3client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().withRegion(region).withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(credentials)).build();
}
private void uploadFileTos3bucket(String fileName, File file) {
    s3client.putObject(new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, fileName, file)
            .withCannedAcl(CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead));
}

public void deleteFileFromS3Bucket(String fileUrl) {
    String fileName = fileUrl.substring(fileUrl.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
    s3client.deleteObject(new DeleteObjectRequest(bucketName + "/", fileName));
}
}
```

The upload function works well, I can see the file has been uploaded to the s3 bucket, but the delete function seems malfunctioning, I get a successful message but the file is still in the bucket.

Thanks in advance if anyone could help me to figure out the problem.

Comment: Are you sure the file path is the same path you uploaded?

Comment: From javadoc `If attempting to delete an object that does not exist, Amazon S3 will return a success message instead of an error message.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just found out that I added an additional slash in `new DeleteObjectRequest`.

Answer (score 3):

From the javadoc of [deleteObject](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3Client.html#deleteObject-com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.DeleteObjectRequest-) (emphasis mine)

> Deletes the specified object in the specified bucket. Once deleted, the object can only be restored if versioning was enabled when the object was deleted.
>   
> **If attempting to delete an object that does not exist, Amazon S3 will return a success message instead of an error message.**

So, most probably the path (`fileName`) you construct in `deleteFileFromS3Bucket` does not point to an S3 object.

**EDIT**

I'm updating my answer based on the comments:

The file name used has special characters (`:` in the provided example) which gets URL encoded (percent encoded). This encoded URL cannot be used to retrieve or delete the S3 object as the percent in the URL would get encoded again(`%` gets encoded to `%25`).

The encoded URL has to be decoded. One way is to use [java.net.URLDecoder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLDecoder.html)

```
URLDecoder.decode(encodedPath, "UTF-8")
```

Comment: the file url is right, I copypasted to the browser and it displays the image what I uploaded.

Comment: @JasminDan Did you verify what is the value of `fileUrl.substring(fileUrl.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);` (fileName)? I suspect it might be wrong (and not the url to which the file was uploaded to )

Comment: @JasminDan (Just to verify your intention here) If `fileUrl` is `a/b/c` then the computed `fileName` will be `b/c` and is the File object passed to `uploadFileTos3bucket` already refers to `b/c` here?

Comment: the fileUrl has some character escaping for special characters, but it is generated automatically by AWS.

Comment: @JasminDan It would be helpful if you can give some example URL (faked ones but with encoding applied)

Comment: image name `cute-cat-picture_1122-449.jpg`, fileUrl returned by aws `bucket_link/2018-02-21T09%3A52%3A09.848-cute-cat-picture_1122-449.jpg`, fileName I give to deleteObject `2018-02-21T09:52:09.848-cute-cat-picture_1122-449.jpg`

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by `fileUrl returned by aws`. Which call returns it? The file name should not contain the timestamp `2018-02-21T09:52:09.848` at the beginning - it must simply be `cute-cat-picture_1122-449.jpg`

Comment: I forgot to mention I added a timestamp to the filename to prevent duplication file name.

Answer (score 2):

```
public boolean deleteFileFromS3Bucket(String fileUrl) {
        String fileName = fileUrl.substring(fileUrl.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
        try {
            DeleteObjectsRequest delObjReq = new DeleteObjectsRequest(bucketName).withKeys(fileName);
            s3client.deleteObjects(delObjReq);
            return true;
        } catch (SdkClientException s) {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

For me, working here is an option.

Answer (score -2):

The only thing that worked for me is deleting it through Cyberduck (I neither work for nor am promoting Cyberduck, I genuinely used it and it worked). Here are the steps of what I did:

1. Download and install Cyberduck.
2. Click on Open Connection
3. Select Amazon S3 from the dropdown (default would be FTP)
4. Enter your access key ID and secret Access key (if you don't have one then you need to create one on your s3 bucket through IAM on AWS).
5. You will see a list your S3 buckets. Select the file or folder or bucket you want to delete, right click and delete. Even files with 0kb show up here and can be deleted.